# Order by NULL while select distinct is used

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Sorry if it is already asked, but I searched and couldnt see the solution. I have a query in MSSQL Server 2008 like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
ProcedureId 
, UserId 
, FacilityId
, LocationId
FROM ....
WHERE ....
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @sortByProcedure = 0 THEN NULL ELSE 1 END,
                   2, 
                   3, 
                   4
```

This query is giving an error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is
>   specified.

It is happening because of the case..when clause, when I remove it, it is working. To what I should replace null there to make it work? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Add that CASE into the select too and it'll work.

Comment: I appreciate if u show..

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include that case statement in the select to be able to sort by it;

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CASE WHEN @sortByProcedure = 0 THEN NULL ELSE 1 END SortField
, ProcedureId 
, UserId 
, FacilityId
, LocationId
FROM ....
WHERE ....
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN @sortByProcedure = 0 THEN NULL ELSE 1 END
, ProcedureId
, UserId
, FacilityId
, LocationId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the column names and `GROUP BY`:

```
Select ProcedureId, UserId, FacilityId, LocationId
From ....
Where ....
group by ProcedureId, UserId, FacilityId, LocationId
order by (case when @sortByProcedure = 0 then null else ProcedureId end),
         UserId, FacilityId, LocationId
```

The numbers for `order by` are (I think) deprecated meaning that support may disappear one day.  In any case, a "1" in the `case` is not interpreted as a column position.

The `GROUP BY` allows you to specify the column names in expressions.  (I'm actually surprised the column name cannot be used for `select distinct`; other databases do allow that construct.)